# Onsen UI show a datepicker on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, onsen-ui

I'm wondering if there is a way to show DatePicker by clicking on some div tag?

```
<input type="date" ...>
```

shows a native datepicker.

Comment: The code you supplied already shows a native date picker. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I want to show a DatePicker not by clicking on an input box but on any element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any datepicker native to Angular. But you can use boostrap's datepicker. It's really easy to use and a simple directive can create the datepicker.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: So, just for DatePicker should I download and integrate the whole package in to my app? That would increase the size of my app a lot. Native Datepicker is not the necessity. Any Datepicker would be fine.

Comment: With this angular boostrap you can't download a single component if you want. If you just need the datepicker, you will just have the module for the datepicker.

Comment: BTW you said you can't download a single component. :P :D

Comment: Yep my bad, it's "you can" obviously ;)